# boost::move and stl algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, boost, stl

Rvalue reference is one of the best feature in c++11, but our old compilers do not support this beautiful creature. After some study, creating a moveable "unique_ptr" is not too hard with the help of boost::move, the better news is that boost::container can work with boost::move too.

My question is, is it possible to make the algorithms like std::swap_range or std::sort benefit from boost::move? Or do I have to write one for my self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in pre-C++11 `std::sort` uses `swap` internally, so as long as you define `swap` appropriately for your class (don't forget ADL), it should use that instead of copying each object.
Move semantics wouldn't do anything significant here.

Comment: Does it *have* to use `swap`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I don't have time for pedantry right now. A reasonable implementation *will* use `swap` in pre-C++11, just as a reasonable implementation will use either swap or move semantics in post-C++11. I'm not sure what an unreasonable implementation is allowed to do (copyability doesn't seem to be a requirement, but neither seems to be swappability) but I really don't care; since it's an optimization anyway, as far as I (and probably the OP) am concerned, that's sufficient.

Comment: It is not pedantry. You claim `std::sort` uses swap,  so it is a genuine question.